# How to get Value from Key from returned MAP in JavaScript in Salesforce lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, map

I m trying to access values in map in JavaScript controller(aura component). Map is being returned from Apex class.

```
var mapVals = response.getReturnValue();
for (var key in mapVals) {
   alert('@@::Key:::'+key); // populating key fine - 
   alert('@@@:::1:::'+mapVals.get(key));// throwing error for this - not supporting get functionality
   alert('@@@@::::2:::'+mapVals.get(key).getReturnValue); // unable to access this as well, trying to pull value
}
```

Response from Apex:
USER_DEBUG [52]|DEBUG|@@@::tValuesMap{--None--=, Business Account 1=Help text of Business Account 1, Business Account 2=Help text of Business Account 2, Channel Partner / Reseller=Help text of  Channel Partner / Reseller, Customer - Channel=Help text of  Customer - Channel, Customer - Direct=Help text of  Customer - Direct, Installation Partner=Help text of  Installation Partner, Other=Help text of Other, Person Account 1=Help text of Person Account 1, Person Account 2=Help text of Person Account 2, ...}

Comment: You can use `Object.keys` method in JS and iterate over it to make sure you are only using properties defined in the object not inherited Or you can use `let val = mapVals[key]` inside the for loop that you have, this is assuming that the return value is an object not a string. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: @manjit5190  - It worked, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys` method in JS and iterate over it to make sure you are only using properties defined in the object not inherited

OR

you can use `let val = mapVals[key]` inside the for loop that you have, this is assuming that the return value is an object not a string.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: mapVals[key] giving single value looking for, object.keys will give all values together, Thanks for support.